# Cannot overfit a simple convolution on a single image

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am working on building a Fully Convolutional Network architecture for image segmentation. For every image, I want to classify every pixel behind either from class #0 (background) or from class #1.

Since my whole network is not working as expected - at all (converging to only predicting the class 0), I simplified it to more elementary network, which is essentially a fully connected layer:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 720, 1280, 3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 720, 1280])
logits= tf.layers.conv2d(X, filters=2, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding="SAME", 
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
labels = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(y, 2)
xentropy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
optimizer = tF.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-1)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

If this network works properly, I expect to overfit a single image fed as input. However this is not the case, as shown by those logs:

```
Epoch 0, train loss: 0.2580, eval loss: 0.5867
Epoch 1, train loss: 0.2572, eval loss: 0.5946
Epoch 2, train loss: 0.2569, eval loss: 0.6009
Epoch 3, train loss: 0.2567, eval loss: 0.6048
Epoch 4, train loss: 0.2567, eval loss: 0.6067
Epoch 5, train loss: 0.2566, eval loss: 0.6072
Epoch 6, train loss: 0.2566, eval loss: 0.6070
Epoch 7, train loss: 0.2566, eval loss: 0.6066
Epoch 8, train loss: 0.2565, eval loss: 0.6061
...
Epoch 686, train loss: 0.2553, eval loss: 0.5916
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this implementation. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Indeed, I edited the post.

Comment: Remove the `relu` activation.

Comment: In the original VGG16 implementation, all convolutional layers are using the ReLU activation function, so it should be working with it. Besides I have tested it without, with no apparent improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: I could not overfit my images because my simple network did not have enough memory to memorize all the input->output mapping (720*1280=921600 mappings) with only 2 filters with a 1x1 convolution (2*3=6 neurons).

The solution has been to come back to a FCN32 implementation and try overfitting a 512x512 subsample of one image. Thanks to the pooling layers, before upsampling, the per pixel classification is done on a 16x16 image. Given the size of the FC layers (2 layers of 4096 filters and 1 layer of 2 filters - binary classification), it was able to overfit properly. I then tried with an image of 720x1280 and it worked as well.